# Clearcase hudson issue

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, clearcase

I have configured ClearCase plugin in Hudson .

I created a project , by giving new `hudson_view_name` as view name for the Hudson project and provided config spec.
I identified in my view storage directory it is creating multiple folders related to the view. like ,

- `hudson_view_name.vws`
- `hudson_view_name.1.vws`
- `hudson_view_name.2.vws`

, but when I see my "`cleartool lsview`" command only `hudson_view_name.vws` is visible not the `hudson_view_name.x.vws`.

When I do the following command:

```
cleartool rmview -force -tag hudson_view_name
```

- `hudson_view_name.2.vws` is being removed but hudson_view_name.vws and
- `hudson_view_name.1.vws` remains , How can I remove those two as well.

Another question is why Hudson created many view storage locations like `viewname.x.vws`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`viewname.x.vws` is the naming convention for **view storage** for views whose tag is reused.
That is the case when the view is not deleted on the client side, but only on the view server side (i.e "`cleartool unregister`", followed by a "`cleartool rmtag`"):
The view is essentially gone for ClearCase, but its client-side view storage (which is now useless) remains.
(That is what [Trent Fisher](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/~trent) says in [his comment](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/ClearCase+Plugin?focusedCommentId=43713570#comment-43713570) of the [Hudson ClearCase Plugin page](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/ClearCase+Plugin))

In this scenario, you can re-create a view by reusing the former view tag, but, since a corresponding view storage still exists, a new `storage.x.vws` is created.

I would really-really recommend selecting the option "use existing dynamic view" to avoid that:

[image]

(but contrary to this picture, I would not select the "Do not reset the config spec").

Comment: Now , How can I remove those entries hudson_view_name.1.vws hudson_view_name.x.vws , which are showing on the view storage location eg: \\servername\views\username\ , this is the place where all my views are stored in server. The problem is even the actual view is deleted , but these two left out entries are still taking my server space.

Comment: @srinannapa: those old `x.vws` view storage directories are no longer used by ClearCase: you can simply remove them (`rmdir`). That will also avoid the creation of new `x.vws` when re-creating a view with the same tag than an older view unregistered and rmtag'ed.